# Angular cli map operator shows supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {Iint} from './iint';
import {Http,Response} from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class Col1col2Service
 {

  constructor(private va:Http) { }
  func2():Observable<Iint[]>
  {

   return this.va.get("http://localhost:50364/api/Default").map((res:Response) 
             => <Iint[]>res.json());
  }
}
```

Iint is an interface created. 
It shows

> [ts]  supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Comment: post your HTML template

Comment: HTML template means what ?

Comment: your HTML code, where you call func2 function

Comment: I did'nt do that. I am stuck in this step.. Should i proceed doing the rest? will the error go after that ?

Comment: i am asking you something else, post your component html

Comment: <div> Helllo </div>

Comment: should i add some reference to any script files in index.html?

Comment: Are you doing proper angular development?

Comment: no. i am not.. i am learning angular

Comment: What you are doing is wrong ,

Comment: Ok. Ill see to it. Thank You so much.

Comment: Read my blog on how to start with angular http://sajeetharan.blogspot.com/2018/01/develop-web-applications-with-angular-5.html?m=1

Comment: I will ...... :-)